# blockstack/pybitcoin different BTC address output

Tags: python, bitcoin, deterministic, passphrase, blockstack

While I was exploring [pybitcoin](https://github.com/blockstack/pybitcoin) I ran the following:

```
from pybitcoin import SDWallet, BitcoinKeypair
passphrase = 'shepherd mais pack rate enamel horace diva filesize maximum really roar mall'
wallet = SDWallet(passphrase)
bitcoin_keypair_1 = wallet.keypair(1, BitcoinKeypair)
bitcoin_keypair_1.passphrase()
>>> 'shepherd mais pack rate enamel horace diva filesize maximum really roar mall bitcoin1'
bitcoin_keypair_1.address()
>>> '1DS2vmsqTwtXp1DfmDHi55Aqc6w4LBUC9k'
```

When I try to generate BTC address [here](https://brainwalletx.github.io/#generator) using the same passphrase "shepherd mais pack rate enamel horace diva filesize maximum really roar mall", I got a different result which is 13mtgVARiB1HiRyCHnKTi6rEwyje5TYKBW

I tried to change the entropy from 160 to 128 in the source code but it doesn't change the result.

What could be the reason why pybitcoin gives different output?
The repository is quite outdated so I haven't post a new issue.

Comment: I hope Ryan Shea can comment on this. :)

Comment: Are you sure the passphrase is not missing the word bitcoin1 at the end? I see two different passphrases in your question.

Comment: oh the "Bitcoin 1" is only to indicate the index. it is not included in the phrase.